# Transform multiple row values to 1 row values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table

```
Id | dwCode| PRNo |
-----------------------
1    DW001    PR001
2    DW001    PR002
```

And I need the following result:

```
dwCode| PRNo |
-----------------------
DW001    PR001,PR002
```

Is there any short way to transform the data like this using MS SQL Server 2005?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`FOR XML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to do so:

```
SELECT 
  t1.dwCode,
  STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + t2.PRNo
    FROM Table1 t2
    WHERE t2.dwCode   = t1.dwCode
    FOR XML PATH (''))
  ,1,2,'') AS PRNo
FROM Table1 t1
GROUP BY t1.dwCode;
```

See it in action here:

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9fb10/1)